# Abstract base classes that implement an interface

Tags: c#

Let's say that I have an abstract base class something simple like

```
abstract class Item : IDisplayable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public abstract void Print();

    }
```

and I have a class that inherits from that like

```
  class Chair: Item
 {
    public int NumberOfLegs {get;set;}

    public void Print()
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Here is a simple interface implementation");
    }
 }

interface IDisplayable
{
void Print();
}
```

the child class does not explicitly say that it also implements the Interface, and yet it will do so through simple inheritance.  If we explicitly add the Interface to the child classes the program will run the same (at least as far as I can tell in my simple examples). Would explicitly implementing the interface be a good or bad idea, or is it strictly a matter of preference?

Comment: Do you mean `Chair: Item`?

Comment: what is `IDisplayable`?

Comment: @DanielA.White just a simple with method a Console.WriteLine

Comment: Note that [`explicit interface implementation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a meaning which I think is different from what you mean.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I thought about while I was typing, but I couldn't think of a better way to write the question, but I can see that it could be confusing.

Comment: Note, with the addition, `Item` needs to at least declare `Print()` as `abstract`, if not implement it. As it stands, it will not compile.

Comment: The close votes are misguided. This is a perfectly good question.

Comment: @EricLippert is your vote that is it redundant to implement each interface on a child class?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: No, it is my opinion that you should only write code that has *the meaning you intend*. If you don't *intend* interface re-implementation semantics then don't *write* interface re-implementation code!

Comment: Also, did you intend `Chair.Print` to be marked `override`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> If we explicitly add the Interface to the child classes the program will run the same (at least as far as I can tell in my simple examples).

The program will not necessarily run the same; your examples are insufficient to illustrate the difference.

> Would explicitly implementing the interface be a good or bad idea, or is it strictly a matter of preference?

It is a bad idea unless you intend to ensure *interface re-implementation semantics*.

Let me illustrate briefly.  What does this program do?

```
using System;
interface IFoo { void Bar(); void Baz(); }
class Alpha : IFoo
{ 
    void IFoo.Bar() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alpha.Bar");
    }
    void IFoo.Baz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alpha.Baz");
    }
}
class Bravo : Alpha
{
    public void Baz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bravo.Baz");
    }
}
class CharlieOne : Bravo
{
    public void Bar() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CharlieOne.Bar");
    }
}
class CharlieTwo : Bravo, IFoo
{
    public void Bar() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CharlieTwo.Bar");
    }
} 
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFoo foo = new Alpha();
        foo.Bar();
        foo.Baz();
        foo = new Bravo();
        foo.Bar();
        foo.Baz();
        foo = new CharlieOne();
        foo.Bar();
        foo.Baz();
        foo = new CharlieTwo();
        foo.Bar();
        foo.Baz();
     }
}
```

Before you read on, seriously: **try to predict the output of this program**.

Now actually run it. **Did you get the output you expected**? Where was your intuition wrong?

Do you see the difference between `CharlieOne` and `CharlieTwo` now?  **Re-implementing `IFoo` in `CharlieTwo` can cause the interface binding to pick up `Bravo.Baz` even though `Bravo` does *not* re-implement `IFoo`!**

And on the other hand: if you expected `Bravo.Baz` to be assigned to the interface slot just because it exists, then you see how *failing* to re-implement an interface causes the code to be incorrect. For `Bravo.Baz` to replace `Alpha.IFoo.Baz`, `Bravo` must re-implement `IFoo`.

The takeaway here is: **when you re-implement an interface, *all* the interface bindings are recomputed *from scratch*.** This can cause semantic changes in your program, so **only re-implement an interface when you mean to do so**.

This also illustrates yet another form of the *brittle base class failure*.  Suppose `Bravo` does not have method `Baz` when you write `Charlie`.  If you write `Charlie` to re-implement `IFoo` then the author of `Bravo` adding `Baz` *afterwards* -- perhaps the authors of `Bravo` are on a different team at your company -- changes the interface bindings within `Charlie` even if that is not what the authors of `Bravo` intended.

For more information, see my article on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/08/so-many-interfaces-part-two.aspx

Comment: Very grateful for you to take the time to make empower strangers through the use of technology +1

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: You're welcome; doing so is my pleasure. And I learn a lot from this site about how people use the product, and how they get it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Item` inherits from `IDisplayable`, anything that derives from `Item` must also implement `IDisplayable`. So explicitly adding `IDisplayable` to those classes is redundant.

EDIT: @EricLippert makes an excellent point below about the effect of re-implementing interfaces. I'm leaving this answer to preserve the discussion in the comments.

Comment: Easy enough, I wasn't searching for any earth-shattering revelations, mainly just convention and real-world examples.

Comment: It's redundant, but it is useful to do so in some circumstances, perhaps to make clear what the class implements? (Personally, I think generally it is *not* useful...)

Comment: With a generic name like `Item`, I agree with @MatthewWatson. To avoid it, I'd recommend using a more specific term from your domain that implies that the item is displayable. Even `DisplayableItem` would be an improvement.

Comment: I wanted to use a very generic example just so people could get the gist without getting into specifics, and it looks like I found an answer: it is...unnecessarily redundant.

Comment: This answer is misleadingly incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'explicitly implementing the interface', I assume that you mean including the interface in the class declaration. There is a different specific meaning to explicitly implementing an interface.
That being said, declaring that the derived class implements an interface that the base class implements is not correct, although the compiler will allow it, *because the derived class contains no implementation of that interface*.
Consider what would happen if the base class explicitly implemented the interface -

```
abstract class Item : IDisplayable
{
    void IDisplayable.Print() { ... }
}
```

Now the derived class has no visibility into the base class method and neither do consumers of the derived class. Of course, consumers ought to be consuming the interface and not the concrete derived class, and then would have access to the explicit interface method. But within the scope of the derived class itself, it is not be aware of interfaces that the base class implements. Only that some members are abstract, protected, or virtual.