# Implementing an interface in a base and derived class

Tags: c#, interface

In C#, can you give a good example of why you would implement an interface on a base class and re-implement that interface on a derived class, rather than making the base class methods virtual.

For example:

```
interface IMakesNoise
{
  void Speak();
}

class Cat : IMakesNoise
{
  public void Speak()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("MEOW");
  }
}

class Lion : Cat, IMakesNoise
{
  public new void Speak()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ROAR");
  }
}
```

To test the behavior:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
Cat lion = new Lion();

// Non virtual calls, acts as expected    
cat.Speak();
lion.Speak();

// Grabbing the interface out is 'virtual' in that it grabs the most derived interface implementation
(cat as IMakesNoise).Speak();
(lion as IMakesNoise).Speak();
```

This will print out:

```
MEOW
MEOW
MEOW
ROAR
```

UPDATE: For more clarification about the *why*, the reason is I am implementing a compiler and I want to know the reason that C# chose this implementation of interfaces.

Comment: For the same reason you'd ever want any method to be non-virtual...I fail to see how the existence of an interface is relevant here at all.

Comment: Your lion implements twice IMakesNoise and it's useless.

Comment: @TopinFrassi It doesn't define it twice, it redefines what the implementation of the interface is, which is not useless, it changes the result of the 4th line of output.

Comment: @TopinFrassi I would say, it only twice implements the Speak method, not the whole interface. But despite that you might find some obscure reasons for having two implementations of Speak method, I would just change the method declaration in `Lion` class to be `public override void Speak()` so that it gets rid of that shizzy `"MEOW"` completely.

Comment: @jmodrak That wouldn't compile, because the method is not virtual in the base class.

Comment: @Servy then, thats the other keyword missing :)

Comment: @jmodrak Then clearly you don't understand the question at all.  The whole point is basically asking why you would ever use this *instead of making the method virtual*.  Saying, "make the method virtual" isn't answering that question at all, nor is it telling the OP anything that he doesn't already know.

Comment: @Servy I see now, blame myself for judging the code not paying attention enough to question. Seeking the obscure, yet still practical, scenario for having the interface reimplemented... unfortunately finding exactly nothing. Or achievable by more common techniques... still, compilable obscurity saves your butt at times.

Comment: @Servy I suppose it's similar to a non-virtual interface (common in C++ templates) and since value-types can implement interfaces, they don't end up getting a v-table. However, it's still 'sort of virtual' in that pulling an interface out of a reference type gives the most derived implementation of the interface, which is what I find to be strange.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at this question.

[Interface inheritance in ComVisible classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399928/interface-inheritance-in-comvisible-classes-in-c-sharp)

and this

[C# exposing to COM - interface inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863128/c-sharp-exposing-to-com-interface-inheritance)

As I understand, if you have two objects and want them to be visible through COM, both should explicitly inherit from the required interface.

Comment: How did COM get involved? Did I miss something?

Comment: @Rick Liddle It is an example - it is a situation, when you may need to "implement an interface on a base class and re-implement that interface"

Comment: OK, I can get on board with that.

Comment: This is more because of how COM works rather than .NET, however it is an interesting reason for this pattern.

Answer (score -1):

If `Lion : Cat` and `Cat : IMakeNoise` then by transitivity, `Lion : IMakeNoise` automatically - declaring it on `Lion` is thus redundant and unnecessary. This is because a `Lion` cannot be a `Cat` without inheriting all of `Cat`s properties - including interfaces.

Virtual methods exist to allow you to not just override, but completely replace functionality within a derivation hierarchy. In other words, you can change the functionality of a less derived class from within a more derived class. This is different from shadowing in that shadowing overrides the functionality of a method for the given derived class only and not the entire class hierarchy.

Shadowing is accomplished by declaring the same non-virtual method which exists in the base class, while adding the `new` keyword to indicate that shadowing behaviour was intended.

Overriding is accomplished by declaring the same `virtual` method which exists in the base class, while adding the `override` keyword to indicate that overriding behaviour was intended.

A code sample will make these differences very clear. Let us define a base `Vehicle` class (as abstract so that it cannot be instantiated) and a deriving `Motorcycle` class. Both will output information to the Console about the number of wheels that they have:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a Vehicle.
/// </summary>
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the Number of Wheels to the Console.
    /// Virtual so can be changed by more derived types.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void VirtualPrintNumberOfWheels()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Wheels: 4");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the Number of Wheels to the Console.
    /// </summary>
    public void ShadowPrintNumberOfWheels()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Wheels: 4");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents a Motorcycle.
/// </summary>
public class Motorcycle : Vehicle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the Number of Wheels to the Console.
    /// Overrides base method.
    /// </summary>
    public override void VirtualPrintNumberOfWheels()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Wheels: 2");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the Number of Wheels to the Console.
    /// Shadows base method.
    /// </summary>
    public new void ShadowPrintNumberOfWheels()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Wheels: 2");
    }
}
```

Above we’ve defined two classes: an abstract base `Vehicle` class which has a virtual and non-virtual method which both do the same thing, and a `Motorcycle` class which implements the `Vehicle` class while overriding the virtual method and shadowing the normal method. Now we will call the methods with different Type signatures to see the differences:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Instantiate a Motorcycle as type Motorcycle
    Motorcycle vehicle = new Motorcycle();

    vehicle.ShadowPrintNumberOfWheels();
    vehicle.VirtualPrintNumberOfWheels();

    // Instantiate a Motorcycle as type Vehicle
    Vehicle otherVehicle = new Motorcycle();

    // Calling Shadow on Motorcycle as Type Vehicle
    otherVehicle.ShadowPrintNumberOfWheels();
    otherVehicle.VirtualPrintNumberOfWheels();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The results:

```
Number of Wheels: 2
Number of Wheels: 2
Number of Wheels: 4
Number of Wheels: 2
```

Comment: The OP made it painfully clear that he *does* understand the functional difference between the virtual and non-virtual implementations here.  The question is asking, "why would you ever want to use the non-virtual implementation instead of the virtual one".  This doesn't answer that question, instead merely repeating information already in the question.

Comment: Also, your first line is very incorrect.  Yes, `Lion` implements `IMakeNoise` without explicitly re-implementing it, but because in his implementation the method is non-virutal, *re-implementing the interface functionally changes how that interface is implemented, making it and important and semantically meaningful thing to do*.  It is only unnecessary when the implementing method is virtual, which is not the case here, again, bringing up the question of "why would you ever want to do this?"

Comment: @Servy - can you elaborate on your second comment and explain what you mean by *re-implementing the interface functionally changes how that interface is implemented*?

Comment: If `Lion` didn't explicitly re-implement the interface then casting a `Lion` instance to the interface would result in calling the `Cat` implementation of `Speak`, not the `Lion` implementation.  Reimplementing the interface changes that behavior.  You can see this yourself right in the OP's code.  If you remove `IMakeNoise` from `Lion` and re-run his code you'll see "MEOW" printed four times, instead of three.  I know Eric Lippert blogged about the design decisions in this behavior, if you want to know why C# does this.

Comment: Interesting. I never knew this (I suppose because I've never made such a confounded design)... Good to know, thank you @Servy!

Comment: [Found a relevant link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17278802/1159478).  The link to the related blog post is at the end of that SO answer.

Comment: @Servy I will accept that as an answer if you post it. It makes much more sense when used with explicit implementation of interfaces. I almost feel that re-implementing an interface on a derived class when the base class did not explicitly implement the interface should probably be illegal.

Comment: @Rovert When a class is designed in a manor not really intended to be inherited from, such as the situation you've described, it should really just be `sealed`.  That comment of mine explains why the code works, it doesn't explain why you'd want to do this instead of making the method virtual, which is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of issues I have with the code sample above, but I'll set most of them aside and focus on the most significant: It's violating the tenet of programming to an interface, not an implementation. If you change your declaration of the cat and lion instances to the following, the problem you're seeing goes away.

```
IMakesNoise cat = new Cat();
IMakesNoise lion = new Lion();
```

In that case, your output is the expected MEOW, ROAR, MEOW, ROAR. See fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/85UN8w).

Programming to interfaces also frees you to embrace inversion of control/dependency injection much more easily.

Comment: The whole point of the code same is to show the difference between typing the expression as the actual type vs the interface.  He covers *both* possibilities specifically to demonstrate the difference.  You're effectively just removing the first two output values and repeating the 3rd and 4th options twice.  That's simply removing information from the code sample, nothing more.

Comment: @Servy Ok, then I guess my answer to his question ("can you give a good example of why you would implement an interface on a base class and re-implement that interface on a derived class?") boils down to "I wouldn't, and if you program to the interface not the implementation you don't have to."

Comment: Yes, actually *you do*.  If he didn't reimplement the interface here *then the output would be different*.  It would output "MEOW" twice if he didn't reimplement the interface, since the method isn't virtual.

Comment: @Servy Out of curiosity, do you have an answer to his question? I'm curious to see how you'd answer the question as a stand-alone instead of as a series of counters to other answers/comments.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457366/implementing-an-interface-in-a-base-and-derived-class/24457727?noredirect=1#comment37848454_24457366) is basically my answer.  To answer the question brought up in that comment one could simply ask Google, it's a rather common enough question, and the variation here is simply not germane to whatever answers you'd get from them.