# Why explicit interface implementation works that way?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Why does this program print "Child Name" instead of "Base Name"?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var child = new Child();
        Console.WriteLine(((INamedObject)child).Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

interface INamedObject
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class Base : INamedObject
{
    string INamedObject.Name
    {
       get
       {
         return "Base Name";
       }
    }
}

class Child : Base, INamedObject
{
   public string Name
   {
      get
      {
         return "Child Name";
      }
   }
}
```

I expect that when I cast *child* to *INamedObject*, Name property of *INamedObject* explicit implementation will be invoked. But what happens is that Child.Name property is called.

Why when I declare *Child* class like that (removing *INamedObject* from *Child*):

```
class Child : Base
{
   public string Name
   {
      get
      {
         return "Child Name";
      }
   }
}
```

it starts printing "Base Name"?

Comment: You have two implementations of INamedObject. When you cast your object to an interface you get the most derived implementation.

Comment: The child class has *two* implementations of INamedObject.Name, something you always always want to avoid.  But it doesn't confuzzle the CLR, it knows at runtime when it binds the interface that Child has a more direct match that isn't inherited.  Sometimes you *must* use an explicit interface implementation, it was made to resolve an ambiguity when a class implements multiple interfaces that happen to have the same member name, this isn't an example of that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other answers do not correctly identify the C# feature that you have stumbled upon.

You have discovered a somewhat confusing feature of C# called "interface re-implementation".  The rule is that when a derived class *specifically re-states an interface that is already implemented by the base class*, then the compiler *starts over and re-does the interface mapping from scratch*.

If that happens then *methods of more derived types are given precedence over methods of less derived types* because we assume that the developer who is developing the more derived type has a *better* implementation than the developer who developed the base class version. After all, if the derived version was *worse*, the developer would not have implemented it!

This rule allows you to decide whether you want a derived class to replace a base class interface mapping or not, because sometimes you want to, and sometimes you don't.

See my 2011 article about this feature for more details:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/12/08/so-many-interfaces-part-two/

You might also find this answer helpful:

[Abstract base classes that implement an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278333/abstract-base-classes-that-implement-an-interface/17278802#17278802)

For the section of the specification that describes this language feature, see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#interface-re-implementation

Answer (score -1):

Hope this not add to your confusion, but help understand the underlying selection mechanism for members:

```
using System;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var child = new Child();

        PrintNatural(child);
        Console.WriteLine();

        PrintAsINamedObject(child);
        Console.WriteLine();

        PrintAsINamedAndAgedObject(child);
        Console.WriteLine();

        PrintAsBoth(child);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintNatural(Child someChild) {
        Console.WriteLine("Natural Name: " + someChild.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Natural Age: " + someChild.Age);
    }

    private static void PrintAsINamedObject(INamedObject someChild) {
        Console.WriteLine("Name as INamedObject: " + someChild.Name);
    }

    private static void PrintAsINamedAndAgedObject(INamedAndAgedObject someChild) {
        Console.WriteLine("Name as INamedAndAgedObject: " + someChild.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Age as INamedAndAgedObject: " + someChild.Age);
    }

    private static void PrintAsBoth<T>(T instance) where T: INamedObject, INamedAndAgedObject
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Name as Generic: " + instance.Name); does not compile Name is ambiguous to the compiler
        Console.WriteLine("Name as Generic<INamedObject>: " + ((INamedObject)instance).Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Name as Generic<INamedAndAgedObject>: " + ((INamedAndAgedObject)instance).Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Age as Generic: " + instance.Age);
    }
}

interface INamedObject
{
    string Name { get; }
}

interface INamedAndAgedObject
{
   string Name { get; }
   int Age { get; }
}

internal class Base : INamedObject
{
    string INamedObject.Name => "Base Name";
}

internal class Child : Base, INamedObject, INamedAndAgedObject
{
   public string Name => "Child Name";
   public int Age => 1024;

   string INamedObject.Name => "Child Name Explicit (INamedObject)";

   string INamedAndAgedObject.Name => "Child Name Explicit (INamedAndAgedObject)";
   int INamedAndAgedObject.Age => 2048;
}
```

**Output**

```
Natural Name: Child Name
Natural Age: 1024

Name as INamedObject: Child Name

Name as INamedAndAgedObject: Child Name Explicit (INamedAndAgedObject)
Age as INamedAndAgedObject: 2048

Name as Generic<INamedObject>: Child Name
Name as Generic<INamedAndAgedObject>: Child Name Explicit (INamedAndAgedObject)
Age as Generic: 2048
```

The run-time selects the more specific member, when you add `INamedObject` to `Child` it selects the raw `Name` property from `Child`, but when you remove it and use the class "as `INamedObject`" (by explicit casting), the base implementation is selected.

Be aware that Explicit Interface Implementation is best used in other scenarios than with inheritance (as your sample). The intention behind explicit interface implementation is disambiguation of members (methods, properties, etc.) among interfaces with member's conflicts (same signature), when you need to implement those in a single concrete class. See [Explicit Interface Implementation (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) for more details.

You can play with this code sample here: [StackOverflowQ59092900](https://dotnetfiddle.net/teNFET)